# send post request to Wikipedia

Tags: python, post, python-requests, request

I'm trying to send data to Wikipedia, (basically trying to input the word 'python' into Wikipedia search bar and print the content)

Here's what I tried:

```
import requests

payload = {'family': 'wikipedia',
'language': 'en',
'search': 'python',
'language': 'en',
'go': 'Go'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/'
    r = s.get(url)

    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print(r.content)
```

But it doesn't seem to work

This is the website I'm trying to send data to: https://www.wikipedia.org/

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you believe an arbitrary `POST` requests at the root of Wikipedia would trigger search functionality? Can you point to any documentation that explicitly states this as a feature of Wikipedia itself? Would be curious to see how they've got this set up, and even more curious to see exactly how they parse the key/value pairs in what you've passed here as `payload` (where `language` is declared twice).

Comment: ill be honest, I dot understand your question, I'm fairly new to request

Comment: More simply: where have you read that Wikipedia's root will respond to `POST` requests?

Comment: i was following some tutorials, they inspected element after pressing a button and clicked on the network part, where I got the payload data from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is get get the content from submitting python into the wikipedia search bar, you don't need to create a post request.  A simple get request will work fine:

```
search_term = "python"
response = requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{search_term}')
print(response.content)
```

---

So to answer your remaining questions:

> I'll be using post request for logins ect so I want to learn via post request

`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` `UPDATE` HTTP requests are *server side implementations*.  They don't magically exist for everything.  So if Wikipedia decides to not have a `POST` request for searching in the search bar, then that's too bad.  You can't use `POST` to make a search.  You will have to use some other way to search, whatever it is that they support (which from my tests appears to be via a `GET` request)

So even though they might implement `POST` for logins (as they should), not everything necessarily has an associated `POST` request.

> can’t I use post to automate it like logging in and pressing buttons, like what selenium does

Sort of. You can use HTTP requests to make the same HTTP calls that a button would when clicked.  It's not exactly the same as clicking on a button though, since clicking on a button can still do many other things behind the scene in your web browser.  And not every button HTTP call is necessarily a `POST` request.

But that aside, even if you search in Wikipedia using Selenium, it would still end up being a `GET` request because Wikipedia changed the way that searches work (at least based on what you have posted).  They made searches require a `GET` request so you have to make a `GET` request.

TLDR: It may have been possible with `POST` in the past, but it isn't anymore because that was a decision that Wikipedia made.

Comment: I'll be using post request for logins ect so I want to learn via post request

Comment: @codeoftheday It might be outdated info then?  I am using HTTP Trace to track the HTTP calls made when searching on Wikipedia and there are is no POST call made that is remotely similar to what you have.  Only one POST call is made and that is just for analytics.  I'm not sure if he got it from some mobile API or something, but at least on web it seems like it is no longer possible.  If they remove support for it there is literally nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I’m now very confused, can’t I use post to automate it like logging in and pressing buttons, like what selenium does

Comment: @coderoftheday updated my answer, hopefully it helps a little more

Comment: Thankyou, I understand much better now